# How i can do this regex simple?

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex:

```
"\w{4}[A-D]{1}[a-d]*\s*"
```

How can I repeat the part of `[A-D]{1}[a-d]*\s*` several time with something like `*`?

So if I have the expression:

```
"Bed0Dabc Babc Cabb99rrAbaaaa Daa6ab"
```

the regex will give me:

```
"Bed0Dabc Babc Cabb"
"99rrAbaaaa Daa"
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: The example input does not match the regex at all: 1. should the regex start with `\w` (to match any alphanumeric)? 2. there is nothing to match a digit at the end.

Comment: You can get rid of {1} as "exactly one match" is the default anyway if you don't have a quantifier.

Comment: In Python you have to escape the backslashes with a backslash or use the raw string notation.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is invalid and lacks "\" at start, your desired output is also invalid and second string should be "99rrAbaaaa Daa".

I believe what you mean is groups, this is a pretty basic concept though, you should probably read more about regular expressions before using them.
The desired regex:

```
\w{4}([A-D][a-d]*\s*)+
```

Comment: no,i dont want to do it with groups... do you have another solution?

Comment: Use `\w{4}(?:[A-D][a-d]*\s*)+` to use a non-capturing group.

Comment: I cannot imagine why you wouldn't want to do it with groups, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `\s` to the set of characters.

```
import re

data = 'Bed0Dabc Babc Cabb99rrAbaaaa Daa6ab'
pattern = r'\w{4}(?:[A-D][a-d\s]*)+'

matches = re.findall(pattern, data)
```

The result:

```
['Bed0Dabc Babc Cabb', '99rrAbaaaa Daa']
```

The `?:` at the start of the group defines a non-capturing group. If you omit it your result will look like this.

```
['Cabb', 'Daa']
```